# AngularFireList, property valueChanges() show the error Property 'query' is missing in type 'Observable<{}[]>

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire

I'm having a hard time to figure out this error. Here is my code that I'm building in to make a AuthGuard service:

```
user.service.ts:

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';

import {AppUser} from './models/app.user';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  save(user: firebase.User) {
    this.db.object('/users/' + user.uid).update({
      name: user.displayName,
      email: user.email
    });
  }

  get(uid: string): AngularFireList<AppUser> {
    return this.db.list('/users/' + uid).valueChanges();
  }
}
```

The property `.valueChanges()` shows me the error:

:>Property 'query' is missing in type 'Observable<{}[]>

I'm also having issues to get the uid:

```
in AuthGuardService.ts:

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/operator/map';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdminAuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private userService: UserService) { }

  canActivate (): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.auth.user$
      .switchMap(user => this.userService.get(user.uid).valueChanges())
      .map (appUser => appUser.isAdmin);
  }
}
```

The error is:

> message": "Property 'isAdmin' does not exist on type 'AppUser[]'."

app.user.ts:

```
export interface AppUser {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    isAdmin: boolean;
}
```

Can anyone help me to identify how to fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your service your return type is wrong.  You are not returning an `AngularFireList<AppUser>` you're returning an `Observable<AppUser[]>`.

In the guard you're passing an array of users to map, so you'd have to check if the first element is an admin instead.

I'm not that familiar with firebase, but it seems a more appropriate alternative in your case to `db.list()` is `db.object()` to return a single record:

```
/* service */
get(uid: string): Observable<AppUser> {
    return this.db.object<AppUser>('/users/' + uid).valueChanges();
}

/* guard */
canActivate (): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.auth.user$
       .switchMap(user => this.userService.get(user.uid))
       .map (appUser => appUser.isAdmin);
}
```

Comment: Daniel, I get this error changing the code: Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<AppUser>'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'AppUser'.
    Property 'email' is missing in type '{}'.

Tks, anyway for your help.

Comment: I see that there is a generic version of object where you can specify the type.  Setting the generic parameter to AppUser should do the trick.  I have updating my answer accordingly.  Otherwise you'd have to cast the result after the call so it matches the callback signature (this is something to avoid).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
user.service.ts:

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';

import {AppUser} from './models/app.user';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {


  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  save(user: firebase.User) {
    this.db.object('/users/' + user.uid).update({
      name: user.displayName,
      email: user.email
    });
  }

  get(uid: string): AngularFireObject<AppUser> {
      return this.db.object('/users/' + uid);
  }

}

In admin-auth-guard.service.ts:

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/operator/map';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';




@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdminAuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private userService: UserService) { }

   canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
      return this.auth.user$
      .switchMap(user => this.userService.get(user.uid).valueChanges())
      .map (appUser => appUser.isAdmin);
     }
}
```

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

In get() method use

```
AngularFireObject<AppUser>
```

Insted of

```
Observable<AppUser>
```